# Make part of a writable book read only

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I want to make an input system tool for some data packs, and add buttons to press when you are done inputting.  The problem is the person inputting text, can delete the buttons, and then the input won’t get processed.  Is there a way to make part of a writable book read only?  I thought of continually modifying the book to keep in the buttons, but I’m pretty sure it will kick you out of the book.  Any help?

Comment: an alternative would be to use chat. as the input system

Comment: @Topcode any idea how I would do that?

Comment: It turns out that editable books do not use JSON text. Signed books do, but books that are still editable use plain text.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the text to be locked in when they submit, a alternative would to tell the player to sign the book when they're done, and test for a `written_book` in the inventory.

```
/say Enter your text, and sign the book when you're done!
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:written_book"}]}] run say Thanks for writing your text!
```

Also, it appears that the Book and Quill uses plain text in NBT for its pages, not JSON text. Signed books use JSON text, but editable books do not.